# How can I make a Stripe subscription in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a Stripe subscription in my Flutter app, however, I couldn't find anything online that could satisfy my requests. I searched into different websites, YouTube and the Stripe documentation too (which doesn't show any Flutter code). I just need to add 3 different types of subscriptions (recurring payment).

Does someone know how to do it? I really need help

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe provides access to the stripe apis, but you will need a backend to handle a lot of the intent generation and stuff. Its also worth noting that depending on what your subscription is for you might be forced to use in app purchases instead of your own provider.

If you add more detail on your backend and what you are trying to achieve i can provide more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe does not provide first-party Flutter support currently.

Stripe's guides for building a Subscription integration will help you understand the server-side part of the flow that needs to be built:
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?platform=react-native

But for the client-side portion, for collecting payment method details, you'll likely want to look into leveraging a prebuilt third-party package for that such as flutter_stripe.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe

Comment: So, if I want to make a subscription plan, do I need to integrate my Flutter code with another language that is supported by Stripe?